# How to convert single space to float in delphi 10

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

am trying convert string to float,when i am passing single char it is giving exceptions.

```
FMandateSize := StrToFloat(EditMandateSize.Text);
```

any idea how to convert single char to float?

Comment: I can't reconstruct this error if I have a number in the edit-field.
Could you provide some more information:
Which exception is raised?
Which char is in the Edit-field?
What type of var is FMandateSize?

Comment: -1. Poor description of the problem. Describe the exceptions you say you get. What was your input, what output did you receive, and what output did you *expect* to see instead? How does the output compare with what the documentation says you should expect?

Comment: Between the subject and the question itself, I interpreted this as an invalid input problem.

Comment: FMandateSize is float value,when i am passing single char am facing exception.I replaced single char with null now am not getting any excpetion..i was in hurry so didnt explained the problem mush..thanks for heads up :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What floating point value would you expect from a space character?  Probably 0.0.

You could use StrToFloatDef to assign your own default value for invalid strings:

```
FMandateSize := StrToFloatDef(EditMandateSize.Text, 0.0);
```

Or you could use TryStrToFloat which gives you a boolean result instead of throwing an exception when there's an invalid string.

```
Result := TryStrToFloat(EditMandateSize.Text, FMandateSize);
```

Comment: What specifically do you mean?  StrToFloat also fails when passed an empty string or NULL.